# AVAudioSession setActive:NO doesn't work the second time

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

I display adds in my application and I need to stop the background music played on the iphone when the add starts and to resume it when the add ends. The first time it work perfect, but the second time I trigger the add the background sound stops but doesn't resume. 
Before the add starts I use:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:nil]; [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

And after:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:&error]; 
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: NO withOptions: AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error: &error];
```

I debugged and find out that first time I call `setActive:NO` I get:

> NSOSStatusErrorDomain with code 560030580

Comment: do you have any connections to airplay ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resume background audio after AVAudioPlayer is paused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216428/resume-background-audio-after-avaudioplayer-is-paused)